# White space under wrapfigure caption

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

Wrapfigure environment has excessive whitespace BELOW the caption.  Inserting negative vspace just shifts the position of the caption relative to the image, actually increasing the 2+ lines of pointless space that usually sit below it.  Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `wrapfig` has an optional argument specifying the no. of lines to reserve, e.g. `\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{i}[0pt]{0.5\textwidth}` -- where 11 is the no. of lines. I usually just play with this number until I get the desired spacing.

Comment: `floatfigure` from the package `floatfig` has much better spacing defaults than `wrapfigure`, but it doesn't play well with sectioning commands (especially the inline ones, like `\paragraph`)

Answer (score 45):

As @prettygully says, the `wrapfigure` environment takes an optional 1st argument called `number of narrow lines`; from the documentation:

[image]

Compare the following (default):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering
\rule{20pt}{10pt}
\caption{My caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

To this, with `number of narrow lines` set as `4`:

```
...
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{3cm}
...
```

[image]

This is a little fiddly- perhaps someone knows of a way to change this globally.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change it globally, e.g., always one line less than it thinks...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to [`wrapfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) is provided by the (much older) [`picins` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/picins). It has a similar setup in terms of horizontal and vertical displacement. Here's a working minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{picins,lipsum}
% Use [demo] option to graphicx if you don't have tiger.pdf
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\pichskip{15pt}% Horizontal gap between picture and text
\parpic[r][t]{%
  \begin{minipage}{40mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tiger}%
    \captionof{figure}{This is a tiger.}
  \end{minipage}
}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The image (or any `<content>`) is placed using `\parpic[<options>][<position>]{<content>}` (you're also able to specify some horizontal/vertical width/height and offset; see the [`picins` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/picins.txt)). `<options>` are for the image location in the paragraph (left `l` or right `r`), while `<position>` refers to alignment within the `\parpic` (left `l`, top `t`, bottom `b` or right `r`). There are also some other elementary framing and shadow commands available.

Horizontal image placement is modified using `\parhskip{<len>}`, while vertical number-of-lines is altered by `\parskip{<n>}`. I've seen that the vertical height of the `\parpic` does not adhere to the `\parskip` command when used with the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof` command. However, you can manually add content below the figure to increase the gap between the caption and the paragraph text below it, if needed. Or, use the `height` parameter in `\parpic(<width>,<height>)...`.

Some additional context related to the use of the `picins` package:

1. `picins` needs to be downloaded manually due it's current license. See [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764) for an option on handling/using manually-downloaded content.
2. It seems to (at least in LuaTeX) prevent `\linewidth` from working within the shorter lines next to the picture. As a pseudo solution you can determine the space left over in your line with the [`linegoal` package](//ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) in the following way:

   ```
   % Before the loading in LuaTeX you need to enable the pdfTeX commands of savepos
   % If you do not use LuaTeX you should leave out these lines
   \let\pdfsavepos\savepos
   \let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos
   \let\pdflastypos\lastypos
   \usepackage{linegoal}

   % Now you declare your measuring command
   \newlength{\leftoverline}
   \newcommand*{\testleftoverwidth}{%
     \noindent\mbox{}%
     \setlength{\leftoverline}{\linegoal}}
   ```

   Afterwards you can now use `\leftoverline` as the width for a parbox/colorbox/pictures, *etc.*

Comment: It should be noted that **picins** is not in TeX Live (it has a nonfree license).

Answer (score 3):

I personnally use mostly `floatingfigure` from the `floatflt` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage{floatflt}

\begin{document}
\begin{floatingfigure}{3cm}
\centering
\rule{20pt}{10pt}
\caption{My caption}
\end{floatingfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The spacing is much more pleasing than `wrapfigure`. However, it has drawbacks: it doesn't do well with sectioning commands, especially inline ones like `\paragraph`, and if a figure hits a page boudary, it's just lost. `wrapfigure`, on the other hand, handles both page breaks and sectioning commands much better.

Comment: It turns out this is not my preferred way to handle this anymore...

Comment: and whats your favorite now? ;)

Comment: ah got it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606450/281453 :D

Answer (score 2):

**Original (Rus)**
Опциональный аргумент (number of narrow lines), задающий количество линий под фигуру следует использовать только в случае, если Вам необходимо "подогнать" размеры конкретного изображения. В остальном проще всего настроить отступ после *caption*

Добавь в преамбулу строку:

```
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-.8\baselineskip}
```

При необходимости размер отступа можно скорректировать.

**Translate (en)**
The optional argument (number of narrow lines) specifying the number of lines for a shape should be used only if you need to "fit" the dimensions of a particular image. Otherwise, the easiest way to adjust the indent after *caption*

Add a line to the preamble:

```
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-.8\baselineskip}
```

If necessary, the indent size can be adjusted.

Comment: where exactly should I position this command?

Answer (score 2):

Since my [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/white-space-under-wrapfigure-caption/351554#351554), I have switched back to using `wrapfigure`, because I ran into a couple of issues with `floatflt` that I couldn't resolve, with figures lost without warning. The trick is simply to add negative `\vspace` at the beginning and at the end of the `wrapfigure` environment. I find this strategy much nicer than to count the lines, and it also offers the possibility to use some space above the first line if desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering
\rule{20pt}{10pt}
\caption{My caption}
\vspace{-3mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This way, you can adjust the spacing manually, it will adapt mostly fine if the vertical size of the figure changes, and it handles much better sectioning commands.