# wrapfigure at the bottom - no white space below wrapfigure

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, wrapfigure

I want to place some figures at the left or right side of my book resulting into a reduced column width for the text. So I am using `wrapfigure` environment with number of narrow lines of 40. By this way the figure covers the whole page. However, I want  the figure to be place at the bottom and the white space above the figure. How can a realize this?

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[40]{O}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Fig3-Givonis-bioclimaticchart}
  \caption[Givoni's bioclimatic chart for four representative climate zones of Nepal]
    {Givoni's bioclimatic chart for four representative climate zones of Nepal}
  \label{fig:Fig3-Givonis-bioclimaticchart}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Read [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/white-space-under-wrapfigure-caption)

Comment: If you are doing this on every page or most pages the flowfram package may be worth exploring.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23313/4778 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111393/4778.

Comment: The wrapfigue package isn't set up to delay the start of the figure, or even start in the middle of a paragraph.  You can achieve this effect using hanging indentation, but it will take some trial an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments and ideas. @AubreyBlumsohn, I am trying to work with flowframe figure but I cannot find approriate example for my case. How would the flowframe definition look like for this pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `\parbox` any taller, it won't fit on the page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.4\textwidth}
  \parbox[b][\dimexpr \textheight-\baselineskip][b]{0.4\textwidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.6\textheight]{example-image}
    \caption{caption}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

---

An alternative is to use paracol.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\setcolumnwidth{{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth-\columnsep},0.4\textwidth}
\twosided[c]
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \sloppy
  \lipsum[1-4]
\switchcolumn
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.6\textheight]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{caption}
  \newpage
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `tikzpagenodes` to place the image at the bottom of the page.  Each paragraph has to be tested for overlap and adjusted.  Move the text up or down and you have to do it all over again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\overlap}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[above right,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.south west) {%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4.5in]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{caption}
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\overlap=\dimexpr 0.4\textwidth + \columnsep\relax% for example

\lipsum[1]% no overlap
\hangindent=\overlap
\hangafter=3
\lipsum[2]% 3 lines before overlap
\leftskip=\overlap
\lipsum[3]% paragraph completely overlapped
\leftskip=0pt
\hangindent=\overlap
\hangafter=-5
\lipsum[4]% 5 lines vefore end of page
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo. But I want to have the space above the figure as white space (NO TEXT). So, maybe `tikzpagenodes` is not the right approach to the problem?