# Margin figure sometime looks awkward

Tags: floats, tufte

I'm typesetting my document with `tufte-book` class which has an environment called `marginfigure`. it's good but sometime it doesn't fit my picture in document well. for example in this MW:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{biditufte-book}

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}


\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{مشاهده‌‌پذیری}
    \ptext[1-4]
    \section{مقدمه}
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\coordinate (a) at (1,{sin(1 r)});
\coordinate (b) at (-1,{sin(-1 r)});
\draw[dashed] (a|-o) node[below] {$x$} -- (a) -- (a-|o) node[left] {$f(x)$};
\draw[dashed] (b-|o) node[right] {$-f(x)$} -- (b) -- (b|-o) node[above] {$-x$};
\draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ نمونه ای از یک تابع فرد}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2]
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\coordinate (a) at (1,{cos(1 r)});
\coordinate (b) at (-1,{cos(-1 r)});
\draw[dashed] (a|-o) node[below] {$x$} -- (a) -- (a-|o);
\draw[dashed] (b-|o) node[above] {$f(x)$} -- (b) -- (b|-o) node[below] {$-x$};
\draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ نمونه ای از یک تابع زوج}
\end{marginfigure}
    \section{مقدمه}
    \ptext[1]

\end{document}
```

My picture is not completely in page. Is there a way of preventing that happening?

[image]

Comment: The key is that it (or at least memoir) uses \marginpar to place the image (which is saved using lrbox).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292394/wrapfigure-at-the-bottom-no-white-space-below-wrapfigure/292588?s=5|0.7665#292588

Comment: Could you put both tikzpictures into one \marginfigure?  Two captions in one figure (or minipage) is no problem.

Comment: As far as I can see `\marginpar` cannot move stuff up, only down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro `\marginpar` is fed a `minipage` by `\marginfigure` which causes the center of the figure to be aligned to the baseline of the text.  This means that the bottom of the figure can protrude below the text area.  One can raise it using `\raisebox`, but one must first determine how much space is left on the page.

This can be done several ways, but the easiest is to use `tikzpagenodes`.

Note: I am unable to get biditufte-book to work, so am using tufte-book instead.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newlength{\DistanceToBottom}
\newcommand{\GetDistanceToBottom}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \pgfextracty{\DistanceToBottom}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}%
    {\pgfpointorigin}}%
  \global\DistanceToBottom=\DistanceToBottom}}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \@tufte@caption@font%
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \@tufte@caption@justification%
    \@tufte@margin@par%
    \noindent%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\GetDistanceToBottom
    \ifdim\DistanceToBottom>\dp\@tufte@margin@floatbox
      \usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
    \else
      \raisebox{\dimexpr \dp\@tufte@margin@floatbox-\DistanceToBottom}%
        {\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
    \fi
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{1em}{40\baselineskip}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \rule{\marginparwidth}{20\baselineskip}
\end{marginfigure}

\the\DistanceToBottom\par
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]