# Positioning of /marginpar

Tags: marginpar

I'm looking for a easy way to specify which side of my document my `\marginpar` is placed in.

Im doing a twosided document with 2 columns. I have one large margin specified for margin-pictures, but when the `\marginpar` (The margin picture) is anchored at a line placed in the column placed at the opposite site margin specified for margin-pictures, they are placed in the wrong margin.

See the picture further illustration.

[image: I want to specifi that the picture should med place in the oppesite margin]

This is the trimmed down code. I have tried to remove everything unrelevent.

```
\documentclass[landscape,]{report}

\usepackage[danish]{babel} % Sætter sproget til dansk

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=8.7 cm, top=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=6.2cm, marginparsep=10mm,twocolumn]{geometry} %sætter vores margins

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % space between columns

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} %Bruges til at lave flere colonder i table of content

\usepackage{subfiles} %Gør det muligt at indsætte filer i vores Main

\usepackage{graphicx} %Tillader indsætning af billeder

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%Tillader justeringer af billeder

\usepackage{placeins} %Tillader commandoen captionof som bruges til billedtekst under billederne. 
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}



\section{Projektbeskrivelse}

\subsection{Forklaring}
Bachelorprojektet omhandler redesign af en eksisterende prototype af Flowtech Medicals
tryksårs forebyggende sæde, baseret på APR-systemet (Active Pressure Relief).
Devicet er tiltænkt bl.a. kørestolsbrugere og andre med tilbøjelighed til at udvikle tryksår.
Redesignprocessen indebærer løbende iterativ prototyping med henblik på materialer,
udformning, konstruktion og brugskontekst i samarbejde med eksterne parter.


\subsection{Problemet}
Tryksår er et problem for millioner af mennesker, der i forvejen er svækket. Ingen pude er blød
nok til, at man kan undgå et tryksår, hvis man sidder stille. Samtidig kan man få tryksår fra selv
små ting som fx. et høreapparat. Det er især folk med lammelser eller nervesygdomme, der er i
risikozonen, da disse har mistet fornemmelsen og førligheden i deres ben. En stor del af disse
mennesker er kørestolsbrugere, som er rygmarvsskadede eller lider af alzheimers eller demens.
Disse mennesker har derfor hjemmepleje eller pårørende, som skal løfte dem fra deres sæde
jævnligt for at undgå tryksår.

I Danmark alene bruger vi millioner af kroner på at forebygge og behandle tryksår.
Sundhedspersonale er ansat til at løfte patienterne hver femte time i forskellige
plejesammenhænge (hjemme, plejehjem og sygehusafdelinger), hvilket er dyrt og stadig alt for sjældent ifølge eksperter.



Flowtech-medical har en vision om at løse problemet vha. deres APR-sæde. Indtil videre er
sædet en prototype, og der er mange områder, der skal redesignes. Der er forskellige aspekter:

\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af den sorte “piratos”, så kanten ikke strækker brugerens hus
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af huller til hydraulisk væske ved indgang til stempler
    \item[$\bullet$] Indfør IoT i produktet
\end{description}

I en forbindelse, hvor sædet bliver en løsning, skal der overvejes nye roller for eksempelvis
plejepersonale.

Brugere anvender allerede forskellige produkter, der aflaster deres udfordringer som vi vil
undersøge og sammenligne med APR-sæde for at finde eventuelle principper vi kan få gavn af.%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234}}
    }



\end{document}
```

---

original MWE

```
\documentclass[landscape,]{report}

\usepackage[danish]{babel} % Sætter sproget til dansk

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=8.7 cm, top=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=6.2cm, marginparsep=10mm,twocolumn]{geometry} %sætter vores margins

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % space between columns

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} %Bruges til at lave flere colonder i table of content

\usepackage{subfiles} %Gør det muligt at indsætte filer i vores Main

\usepackage{graphicx} %Tillader indsætning af billeder

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%Tillader justeringer af billeder

\usepackage{placeins} %Tillader commandoen captionof som bruges til billedtekst under billederne. 

\begin{document}



\section{Projektbeskrivelse}

\subsection{Forklaring}
Bachelorprojektet omhandler redesign af en eksisterende prototype af Flowtech Medicals
tryksårs forebyggende sæde, baseret på APR-systemet (Active Pressure Relief).
Devicet er tiltænkt bl.a. kørestolsbrugere og andre med tilbøjelighed til at udvikle tryksår.
Redesignprocessen indebærer løbende iterativ prototyping med henblik på materialer,
udformning, konstruktion og brugskontekst i samarbejde med eksterne parter.

\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{Fig/Valgteprinci.png}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234}}
    }

\subsection{Problemet}
Tryksår er et problem for millioner af mennesker, der i forvejen er svækket. Ingen pude er blød
nok til, at man kan undgå et tryksår, hvis man sidder stille. Samtidig kan man få tryksår fra selv
små ting som fx. et høreapparat. Det er især folk med lammelser eller nervesygdomme, der er i
risikozonen, da disse har mistet fornemmelsen og førligheden i deres ben. En stor del af disse
mennesker er kørestolsbrugere, som er rygmarvsskadede eller lider af alzheimers eller demens.
Disse mennesker har derfor hjemmepleje eller pårørende, som skal løfte dem fra deres sæde
jævnligt for at undgå tryksår.\\
\newline
I Danmark alene bruger vi millioner af kroner på at forebygge og behandle tryksår.
Sundhedspersonale er ansat til at løfte patienterne hver femte time i forskellige
plejesammenhænge (hjemme, plejehjem og sygehusafdelinger), hvilket er dyrt og stadig alt for sjældent ifølge eksperter.\\
\newline


Flowtech-medical har en vision om at løse problemet vha. deres APR-sæde. Indtil videre er
sædet en prototype, og der er mange områder, der skal redesignes. Der er forskellige aspekter:\\

\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af den sorte “piratos”, så kanten ikke strækker brugerens hus
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af huller til hydraulisk væske ved indgang til stempler
    \item[$\bullet$] Indfør IoT i produktet
\end{description}
 \\
I en forbindelse, hvor sædet bliver en løsning, skal der overvejes nye roller for eksempelvis
plejepersonale.\\
\newline
Brugere anvender allerede forskellige produkter, der aflaster deres udfordringer som vi vil
undersøge og sammenligne med APR-sæde for at finde eventuelle principper vi kan få gavn af.

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a version of the test file which runs without error and hopefully illustrates the intended problem with the marginpar on the wrong side. Feel free to revert that chaneg if you do not like it, but the original version gives errors unrelated to the question.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413580/how-to-correctly-change-the-side-that-marginpar-appears-per-case

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this

[image]

which moves marginpars from the second column to the left margin. Note as here this can make a later marginpar (from the top of column 2) appear before an earlier one (from column 1) and no collision detection is done so they may overprint and need manual adjustment.

```
\documentclass[landscape,]{report}

\usepackage[danish]{babel} % Sætter sproget til dansk

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=8.7 cm, top=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=6.2cm, marginparsep=10mm,twocolumn]{geometry} %sætter vores margins

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % space between columns

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} %Bruges til at lave flere colonder i table of content

\usepackage{subfiles} %Gør det muligt at indsætte filer i vores Main

\usepackage{graphicx} %Tillader indsætning af billeder

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%Tillader justeringer af billeder

\usepackage{placeins} %Tillader commandoen captionof som bruges til billedtekst under billederne. 
\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\def\@addmarginpar{\@next\@marbox\@currlist{\@cons\@freelist\@marbox
    \@cons\@freelist\@currbox}\@latexbug\@tempcnta\@ne
    \if@twocolumn
        \if@firstcolumn \@tempcnta\m@ne \fi
    \else
      \if@mparswitch
         \ifodd\c@page \else\@tempcnta\m@ne \fi
      \fi
      \if@reversemargin \@tempcnta -\@tempcnta \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\@tempcnta <\z@  \global\setbox\@marbox\box\@currbox \fi
    \@tempdima\@mparbottom
    \advance\@tempdima -\@pageht
    \advance\@tempdima\ht\@marbox
    \ifdim\@tempdima >\z@
      \@latex@warning@no@line {Marginpar on page \thepage\space moved}%
    \else
      \@tempdima\z@
    \fi
    \global\@mparbottom\@pageht
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\@tempdima
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\dp\@marbox
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\marginparpush
    \advance\@tempdima -\ht\@marbox
    \global\setbox \@marbox
                   \vbox {\vskip \@tempdima
                          \box \@marbox}%
    \global \ht\@marbox \z@
    \global \dp\@marbox \z@
    \kern -\@pagedp
    \nointerlineskip
    \hb@xt@\columnwidth
      {\ifnum \@tempcnta >\z@
          \hskip-\columnwidth \hskip-\columnsep
       \fi
          \hskip -\marginparsep \hskip -\marginparwidth
       \box\@marbox \hss}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \hbox{\vrule \@height\z@ \@width\z@ \@depth\@pagedp}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}



\section{Projektbeskrivelse}

\subsection{Forklaring}
Bachelorprojektet omhandler redesign af en eksisterende prototype af Flowtech Medicals
tryksårs forebyggende sæde, baseret på APR-systemet (Active Pressure Relief).
Devicet er tiltænkt bl.a. kørestolsbrugere og andre med tilbøjelighed til at udvikle tryksår.
Redesignprocessen indebærer løbende iterativ prototyping med henblik på materialer,
udformning, konstruktion og brugskontekst i samarbejde med eksterne parter.


\subsection{Problemet}
Tryksår er et problem for millioner af mennesker, der i forvejen er svækket. Ingen pude er blød
nok til, at man kan undgå et tryksår, hvis man sidder stille. Samtidig kan man få tryksår fra selv
små ting som fx. et høreapparat. Det er især folk med lammelser eller nervesygdomme, der er i
risikozonen, da disse har mistet fornemmelsen og førligheden i deres ben. En stor del af disse
mennesker er kørestolsbrugere, som er rygmarvsskadede eller lider af alzheimers eller demens.
Disse mennesker har derfor hjemmepleje eller pårørende, som skal løfte dem fra deres sæde
jævnligt for at undgå tryksår.

I Danmark alene bruger vi millioner af kroner på at forebygge og behandle tryksår.
Sundhedspersonale er ansat til at løfte patienterne hver femte time i forskellige
plejesammenhænge (hjemme, plejehjem og sygehusafdelinger), hvilket er dyrt og stadig alt for sjældent ifølge eksperter.



Flowtech-medical har en vision om at løse problemet vha. deres APR-sæde. Indtil videre er
sædet en prototype, og der er mange områder, der skal redesignes. Der er forskellige aspekter:%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234}}
    }


\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af den sorte “piratos”, så kanten ikke strækker brugerens hus
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af huller til hydraulisk væske ved indgang til stempler
    \item[$\bullet$] Indfør IoT i produktet
\end{description}

I en forbindelse, hvor sædet bliver en løsning, skal der overvejes nye roller for eksempelvis
plejepersonale.

Brugere anvender allerede forskellige produkter, der aflaster deres udfordringer som vi vil
undersøge og sammenligne med APR-sæde for at finde eventuelle principper vi kan få gavn af.%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234b}}
    }



\end{document}
```

---

**Two side version**

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[danish]{babel} % Sætter sproget til dansk

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=8.7 cm, top=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=6.2cm, marginparsep=10mm,twocolumn]{geometry} %sætter vores margins

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % space between columns

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc} %Bruges til at lave flere colonder i table of content

\usepackage{subfiles} %Gør det muligt at indsætte filer i vores Main

\usepackage{graphicx} %Tillader indsætning af billeder

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%Tillader justeringer af billeder

\usepackage{placeins} %Tillader commandoen captionof som bruges til billedtekst under billederne. 
\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\def\@addmarginpar{\@next\@marbox\@currlist{\@cons\@freelist\@marbox
    \@cons\@freelist\@currbox}\@latexbug\@tempcnta\@ne
    \if@twocolumn
        \if@firstcolumn \@tempcnta\m@ne \fi
    \else
      \if@mparswitch
         \ifodd\c@page \else\@tempcnta\m@ne \fi
      \fi
      \if@reversemargin \@tempcnta -\@tempcnta \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\@tempcnta <\z@  \global\setbox\@marbox\box\@currbox \fi
    \@tempdima\@mparbottom
    \advance\@tempdima -\@pageht
    \advance\@tempdima\ht\@marbox
    \ifdim\@tempdima >\z@
      \@latex@warning@no@line {Marginpar on page \thepage\space moved}%
    \else
      \@tempdima\z@
    \fi
    \global\@mparbottom\@pageht
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\@tempdima
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\dp\@marbox
    \global\advance\@mparbottom\marginparpush
    \advance\@tempdima -\ht\@marbox
    \global\setbox \@marbox
                   \vbox {\vskip \@tempdima
                          \box \@marbox}%
    \global \ht\@marbox \z@
    \global \dp\@marbox \z@
    \kern -\@pagedp
    \nointerlineskip
    \hb@xt@\columnwidth
      {\ifodd\c@page
       \ifnum \@tempcnta >\z@
          \hskip-\columnwidth \hskip-\columnsep
       \fi
          \hskip -\marginparsep \hskip -\marginparwidth
        \else
       \ifnum \@tempcnta >\z@
          \hskip \columnwidth \hskip \marginparsep 
        \else
       \hskip 2\columnwidth \hskip\columnsep \hskip \marginparsep
       \fi

        \fi
       \box\@marbox \hss}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \hbox{\vrule \@height\z@ \@width\z@ \@depth\@pagedp}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}



\section{Projektbeskrivelse}

\subsection{Forklaring}
Bachelorprojektet omhandler redesign af en eksisterende prototype af Flowtech Medicals
tryksårs forebyggende sæde, baseret på APR-systemet (Active Pressure Relief).
Devicet er tiltænkt bl.a. kørestolsbrugere og andre med tilbøjelighed til at udvikle tryksår.
Redesignprocessen indebærer løbende iterativ prototyping med henblik på materialer,
udformning, konstruktion og brugskontekst i samarbejde med eksterne parter.


\subsection{Problemet}
Tryksår er et problem for millioner af mennesker, der i forvejen er svækket. Ingen pude er blød
nok til, at man kan undgå et tryksår, hvis man sidder stille. Samtidig kan man få tryksår fra selv
små ting som fx. et høreapparat. Det er især folk med lammelser eller nervesygdomme, der er i
risikozonen, da disse har mistet fornemmelsen og førligheden i deres ben. En stor del af disse
mennesker er kørestolsbrugere, som er rygmarvsskadede eller lider af alzheimers eller demens.
Disse mennesker har derfor hjemmepleje eller pårørende, som skal løfte dem fra deres sæde
jævnligt for at undgå tryksår.

I Danmark alene bruger vi millioner af kroner på at forebygge og behandle tryksår.
Sundhedspersonale er ansat til at løfte patienterne hver femte time i forskellige
plejesammenhænge (hjemme, plejehjem og sygehusafdelinger), hvilket er dyrt og stadig alt for sjældent ifølge eksperter.



Flowtech-medical har en vision om at løse problemet vha. deres APR-sæde. Indtil videre er
sædet en prototype, og der er mange områder, der skal redesignes. Der er forskellige aspekter:%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234}}
    }


\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af den sorte “piratos”, så kanten ikke strækker brugerens hus
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af huller til hydraulisk væske ved indgang til stempler
    \item[$\bullet$] Indfør IoT i produktet
\end{description}

I en forbindelse, hvor sædet bliver en løsning, skal der overvejes nye roller for eksempelvis
plejepersonale.

Brugere anvender allerede forskellige produkter, der aflaster deres udfordringer som vi vil
undersøge og sammenligne med APR-sæde for at finde eventuelle principper vi kan få gavn af.%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234b}}
    }


\clearpage


\section{Projektbeskrivelse}

\subsection{Forklaring}
Bachelorprojektet omhandler redesign af en eksisterende prototype af Flowtech Medicals
tryksårs forebyggende sæde, baseret på APR-systemet (Active Pressure Relief).
Devicet er tiltænkt bl.a. kørestolsbrugere og andre med tilbøjelighed til at udvikle tryksår.
Redesignprocessen indebærer løbende iterativ prototyping med henblik på materialer,
udformning, konstruktion og brugskontekst i samarbejde med eksterne parter.


\subsection{Problemet}
Tryksår er et problem for millioner af mennesker, der i forvejen er svækket. Ingen pude er blød
nok til, at man kan undgå et tryksår, hvis man sidder stille. Samtidig kan man få tryksår fra selv
små ting som fx. et høreapparat. Det er især folk med lammelser eller nervesygdomme, der er i
risikozonen, da disse har mistet fornemmelsen og førligheden i deres ben. En stor del af disse
mennesker er kørestolsbrugere, som er rygmarvsskadede eller lider af alzheimers eller demens.
Disse mennesker har derfor hjemmepleje eller pårørende, som skal løfte dem fra deres sæde
jævnligt for at undgå tryksår.

I Danmark alene bruger vi millioner af kroner på at forebygge og behandle tryksår.
Sundhedspersonale er ansat til at løfte patienterne hver femte time i forskellige
plejesammenhænge (hjemme, plejehjem og sygehusafdelinger), hvilket er dyrt og stadig alt for sjældent ifølge eksperter.



Flowtech-medical har en vision om at løse problemet vha. deres APR-sæde. Indtil videre er
sædet en prototype, og der er mange områder, der skal redesignes. Der er forskellige aspekter:%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234c}}
    }


\begin{description}
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af den sorte “piratos”, så kanten ikke strækker brugerens hus
    \item[$\bullet$] Redesign af huller til hydraulisk væske ved indgang til stempler
    \item[$\bullet$] Indfør IoT i produktet
\end{description}

I en forbindelse, hvor sædet bliver en løsning, skal der overvejes nye roller for eksempelvis
plejepersonale.

Brugere anvender allerede forskellige produkter, der aflaster deres udfordringer som vi vil
undersøge og sammenligne med APR-sæde for at finde eventuelle principper vi kan få gavn af.%
\marginpar{
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,right]{example-image}  
    \captionof{figure}{Hvorfor virker det her ikke.
    \label{fig:label1234d}}
    }



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this does not solve the twosided problem, when the margin has switched from left to right at every other page. :(

Comment: @KristofferBlæsbjerg oh it could do, I did the oneside version as you provided a oneside example, `report` class defaults to onesided unless you use the `twoside` option. you said in teh text "twoside" but I tend to read the code more carefully than the text:-) give me a minute I'll update...

Comment: My mistake. I am using the twoside option though.

Comment: @KristofferBlæsbjerg twoside version added

Comment: How stable is maginpar placement actually? There used to be some problems when a paragraph began on one page and continued on the other.

Comment: @OlegLobachev well the code hasn't really changed since about 1985 so yes it can get it wrong sometimes, although a manual insertion of `\reversemarginpar` usually fixes it