# Ending wrapfigure before next section

Tags: wrapfigure, sections-paragraphs

I would like to end the wrapfigure environment before the next paragraph. I have tried to stop wrapping at various line values but to no avail. Ideas? MWE and picture below.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{*Consecutive Value Sequence:} The traditional poker sequence is used for determining consecutive face values – A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A. Lords (L) – including 0. The Fool and 00. The Fox – are considered to have all face values until summoned, at which point they become face value L, which is not consecutive with any other face value. This means that Lords may be field summoned adjacent to any of your in-play cards, but can then only be used as a base by cards that share their suit, and by other Lords. 0. The Fool and 00. The Fox do not share suits with any cards.

\vspace{0.25cm}

Once a card has been summoned, it is in \textbf{play}.

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1.6}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{1-6.png}
\caption{\scriptsize{Basic movement.}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\subsection{Moving Cards} If you have cards in play at the start of your turn, you may move one of them as your turn action. A card can be moved one (1) space, either north, south, east, or west if there is an unoccupied space for your card to be moved into. If the space in question is occupied by an enemy card, refer to the rules for Capturing Cards below. You may not move a card into a space occupied by another one of your cards, and you may not move a card diagonally.

\subsection{Capturing Cards} Your main objective is to defeat your foes by \textbf{capturing} their cards; The first player to earn five (5) captures wins. Capturing cards works like a standard move (see Moving Cards), except that a player’s card moves into a space that is occupied by another player’s card.\\

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: wrapfigure]

Comment: If you aren't actually wrapping the text around the figure in the middle of a paragraph, paracol is a good alternative.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292394/wrapfigure-at-the-bottom-no-white-space-below-wrapfigure/292588?r=SearchResults&s=1|43.2927#292588 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{*Consecutive Value Sequence:} The traditional poker sequence is used for determining consecutive face values – A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A. Lords (L) – including 0. The Fool and 00. The Fox – are considered to have all face values until summoned, at which point they become face value L, which is not consecutive with any other face value. This means that Lords may be field summoned adjacent to any of your in-play cards, but can then only be used as a base by cards that share their suit, and by other Lords. 0. The Fool and 00. The Fox do not share suits with any cards.

\vspace{0.25cm}

Once a card has been summoned, it is in \textbf{play}.


\subsection{Moving Cards}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-A}
    \caption{\scriptsize{Basic movement.}}
\end{wrapfigure}

 If you have cards in play at the start of your turn, you may move one of them as your turn action. A card can be moved one (1) space, either north, south, east, or west if there is an unoccupied space for your card to be moved into. If the space in question is occupied by an enemy card, refer to the rules for Capturing Cards below. You may not move a card into a space occupied by another one of your cards, and you may not move a card diagonally.
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1.6}

\subsection{Capturing Cards} Your main objective is to defeat your foes by \textbf{capturing} their cards; The first player to earn five (5) captures wins. Capturing cards works like a standard move (see Moving Cards), except that a player’s card moves into a space that is occupied by another player’s card.\\

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: out3]

If the figure is taller than the Moving Cards `\subsection` then add some `\vspace` before the following `\subsection`, as:  (using a square figure)

```
\subsection{Moving Cards}

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[0pt]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-A}
    \caption{\scriptsize{Basic movement.}}
\end{wrapfigure}

 If you have cards in play at the start of your turn, you may move one of them as your turn action. A card can be moved one (1) space, either north, south, east, or west if there is an unoccupied space for your card to be moved into. If the space in question is occupied by an enemy card, refer to the rules for Capturing Cards below. You may not move a card into a space occupied by another one of your cards, and you may not move a card diagonally.
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1.6}

\vspace{3\baselineskip} & <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\subsection{Capturing Cards}
```

[image: out4]

Or make the figure smaller, a square of the size of the paragraph height, for better looking.

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-A}
```

[image: out5]